# Local domains redirecting to https Win10 on 3 main browsers

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, https, hosts

This is blowing my head up - for local development I have added some domains to my hosts files as follows:

127.0.0.1 cake.test
127.0.0.1 foobar.test
127.0.0.1 dog.cat

cake.test works fine - all good.

foobar.test and dog.cat (and several others) re-direct to https

the dog.cat domain is a simple index.php - there is not an htaccess or php script to redirect so I'm struggling to understand why this is happening - also on other domains it happens.

This happens in Chrome and Edge and Firefox. Also if I stop my Apache server the page is not found but already the redirect to https has occurred. This would indicate that the redirect is happening at the operating system level (win10 - I know, I know) or network. I am just at a total loss.

I tried flushing my dns with the command:

ipconfig /flushdns

Apache has all SSL options disabled, and as mentioned other local domains work fine, using *.test local domain.

Any suggestions welcome.

**UPDATE**

This gets better... if I take the working domain and then point it to the project which will not load (that is just an index.php echoing "hello world") this now also returns an SSL error. The previously non-working domain will now work.

This is staggering.

Comment: I suggest you read up on HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS).

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my update but if foo.cake works with http, why does it not work when I switch that domain to point to a different folder in my htdocs and restart my server? If the domain works it should work whether it points to site1, 2 or x shouldn't it?

Comment: Further, if I go to: chrome://net-internals/#hsts and I search for the domain it is not found

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion having hit a brick wall after 4 hours of testing is that a major bug is the cause, in conclusion

mydomain.local -> htdocs/site1 = works using http

then switch

mydomain.local -> htdocs/site2 = does not work and redirects to ssl

Seems related to the Win10 this behaviour is observed in Chrome and Firefox.